# I want to display multiple dataframes on the console at once

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to return a list or tuple of dataframes and displaying them, but i am unable to display it, so can someone please help

I have tried to return list(dataframes) and then i am calling .show in my main
method

```
def dbReader():List[DataFrame]= {

val abcd_df_user = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/abcd?user=postgres&password=postgres")
  .option("dbtable", "User_Testing")
  .option("user", "postgres")
  .option("password", "postgres")
  .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
  .load()
  .createOrReplaceTempView("abcd_user_testing")

val user_Testing = spark.sql("""select * from abcd_user_testing""")
//.createOrReplaceTempView("All_User__Data")

val abcd_df_employee = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/abcd?user=postgres&password=postgres")
  .option("dbtable", "employee")
  .option("user", "postgres")
  .option("password", "postgres")
  .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
  .load()
  .createOrReplaceTempView("Employee_Table")

  val employee_df = spark.sql("""select emp_id,emp_name from Employee_Table""")

  List(employee_df,user_Testing)

}
```

Main Method:

```
object readinfromdbusingdf extends App {

  val readingfromdbusingdf=new readingfromdbusingdf()

  readingfromdbusingdf.dbReader().show(10)
```

expected results: It should be displaying both the dataframes on the console

Comment: Maybe `dbReader().foreach(_.show(10))`.

Comment: Yes its working Now, Thanks a Lot!